# Understanding `TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor.` error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using TF2.4 in a custom experimentation framework and use `mlworkflow.lazyproperty` decorator to construct attributes (like the `tf.keras.Model()`) the first time they are accessed.

For most of my deep learning experiments, this framework works very well, but I'm facing a `TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor.` error when trying another head in my experiments.

I managed to reduce the problem to the following minimal working example in which, when using my custom object `Head_1()`, the error is raised, but when using `Head_2(tf.keras.layers.Layer)`, it works fine.

```
import numpy as np
from mlworkflow import lazyproperty

class Head_1():
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return tf.ones((20,25))[tf.newaxis] + inputs[...,0]

class Head_2(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.ones((20,25))[tf.newaxis] + inputs[...,0]

class Experiment():
    @lazyproperty
    def model(self):
        inputs = tf.keras.Input(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(20, 25, 3))
        model = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5, 1)
        head = Head_1()
        logits = model(inputs)
        outputs = head(logits)
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

    @tf.function
    def run(self, data):
        return self.model(data, training=True)

exp = Experiment()
exp.run(np.ones((1, 20, 25, 3), dtype=np.float32))
```

**Can someone explain why `Head_1` passes a «_"Graph" tensor_» to an «_op outside of the function building code_» while `Head_2` doesn't?**

I cannot use `Head_2` because I need my custom object to control what happens inside the `__call__` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create the model before the call to `run`. Specifically

```
exp = Experiment()
_ = exp.model    # creates model before first call of the tf.function
exp.run(np.ones((1, 20, 25, 3), dtype=np.float32))
```